# Solving for x when x is in the denominator of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I have the formula $$f(x) = \frac{xy}{x+y}$$ How do I get the equation in terms of x or y?

Comment: That's not an equation.

Comment: @BobbieD Instead of being snarky, tell me what it actually is, then answer the question

Comment: I can't answer the question.  To isolate $x$ or $y$ you need an equation (i.e. something equals $\frac{xy}{x+y}$).  It seems you've left off the "something equals" part.

Comment: @BobbieD sorry, I've gotten used to being patronized and I overreacted. I will edit the question.

Comment: @script8man No problem. :-)

Comment: Um, it *is* in terms of x.  What more do want.  Do you mean if xa/(x+a) =c, solve for x?  What are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Note: your question doesn't exactly make sense as written.  Here are two interpretations of it.

---

How to isolate $x$ in $z = \dfrac{xy}{x+y}$:

Let $z=\dfrac{xy}{x+y}$ where $x\ne -y$ (to avoid division by zero).

1. Multiply both sides by $x+y$: $$z(x+y) = xy$$
2. Distribute: $$xz + yz = xy$$
3. Move all the terms with $x$ in them to the left and all the terms without $x$ to the right: $$xz - xy = -yz$$
4. Factor out $x$: $$x(z-y) = -yz$$
5. Assuming $z\ne y$ (to avoid division by zero), divide by $z-y$ on both sides: $$x = -\frac{yz}{z-y}\quad \Big(= \frac{yz}{y-z}\Big)$$

---

Rewrite the implicit functional equation $\frac{xy}{x+y} = c$, solving for $y$ as an explicit function of $x$:

Do the exact same steps as above, but solving for $y$ to get $$y = \frac{cx}{x-c}$$ for all $x\ne c$.

Comment: I like how you are much more explicit in each step than I was. Good idea for helping a beginner to algebraic manipulations - a +1 from me for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = f(x)$
$$z = \frac{xy}{x+y}$$
$$z(x+y) = xy$$
$$zx + zy= xy$$
$$zx = xy -zy$$
$$zx = y(x -z)$$
$$\frac{zx}{x-z} = y$$
By symmetry in the original equation, we can let $x \leftrightarrow y$ to get
$$\frac{zy}{y-z} = x$$